# Where is the com.sabre.redapp.example.pnr Sample

Tags: sabre

The help in the 3.2 RC1 SDK mentions a sample (`com.sabre.redapp.example.pnr`) that can access PNRs, but the code is not available in the samples. This seems to be a great feature of SDK 3.0+.

Can the sample be found somewhere else?

> This sample demonstrates access to PNR and refreshing Trip Summary. 
>   When you have a PNR present in your workspace you can clik on "Get PNR" button to get contents of current PNR.The result will be displayed in the text area on the left.
>
> When you need to refresh Trip Summary click on "Refresh Trip Summary" button. You will see the refresh request status in the text area on the left.
>
> NOTE: Refreshing Trip Summary works only in Sabre Red Workspace 3.0. In 2.0 it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, the RC does not contains this sample code. This will be fixed in our next release targeted mid-August

Sample download link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtYtpymTraNPjzY1BzGHF5UViBxr

Comment: So, I got this from RC2, but am having issues running it at the moment...